# Javascript Error: Uncaught Exception[object Object] When Reading From Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, uncaught-exception

I wrote a JavaScript program to read data from a Google Sheet that has been working for several months now.  Recently, the hosting company that I used merged with another system and everything has been transferred over successfully. (I originally used Bitballoon, and that merged with Netlify Drop.)

With this change, my program stopped working, so it led me to believe that the problem resided with the new server.  I then tried to host the site on 000webhost, but when that didn't work, I had no idea what to do.  I have several pages that now all have the same issue, and there were no code changes whatsoever from when it worked to when it stopped working.

The error message appears in the browser console:

> uncaught exception[object Object]

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Here is the code that I use (from [Google's example JS for `spreadsheets.values.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)):

```
function initClient() {
    console.log("initClient happened");
    var API_KEY = /* API KEY*/;

    var CLIENT_ID = /*client ID*/;

    // TODO: Authorize using one of the following scopes:
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';

    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    }).then(function() {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
        updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
}

function handleClientLoad() {
    console.log("handleClientLoad");
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}
```

`initClient()` is called when the page first loads, which then triggers a set of functions that makes the API call.  However, it no longer gets past asking for permission to read, which is what this part of the code is mostly doing.

As far as I can tell, the problem is in the `initClient` function, but I am not sure.  I traced it down to `gapi.client.init`, so I think the problem is with that.

I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Hi U Sin, can you update your answer and add the code you use to import data from the Google Sheet. Also, attach a screenshot of the error and describe when it happens. That will help in debugging your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RoyScheffers I have edited and added what you asked for.  Thanks so much for taking time to look into this.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: No error screenshots. Stack Overflow can't index images (at least not like it can index text). Write the text of your error message in your question, so that you and others can easily find related questions.

Comment: @tehhowch I only added the screenshot so people could see exactly what the console showed as per RoyScheffer's request.  I did write the actual error in the question title, but I just edited my post and clarified exactly what the error said.

Comment: @USin you need to include in your question the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the error. Linking to code is useless when asking for help with a specific part of it, especially tutorials, as they get updated and changed. You should still include a reference to the tutorial or source of your code (i.e. cite your sources).

Comment: I will note that you have a `Promise(...).then(...)` and do not have a corresponding `.catch` block to handle any exceptions that occur (such as failure to authenticate due to bad credentials, revoked scope access, cross origin requests, etc.). If you add the standard logging `.catch`, can you learn more about the error?

Comment: @tehhowch Your suggestion saved me months of work.  I added a catch block to log the error and found out that the problem was simply that I hadn't updated the credentials to match the new domain with the server change.  Thanks so much!  As a side note, you seem more experienced on this forum, so I wanted to ask, should I post an answer to how I solved my problem for future reference?

Comment: If you think your problem & the solution will be useful to others, then you should [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Otherwise, if you think your issue and its solution will not be helpful, consider deleting the question.

Comment: I had the same issue, but in my case, the issue was the order of files being loaded was not correct.